# JMES Path: Exclude top 5 records from AWS CLI results

Tags: aws-cli, jmespath

I would like to get the list of available snapshots for an RDS instance using AWS CLI.

I could get all the snapshots in descending order by the time they're created using this query:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier sample-db \
 --query="(reverse(sort_by(DBSnapshots[?SnapshotType=='manual'], &SnapshotCreateTime)))[*].{DBSnapshotIdentifier: DBSnapshotIdentifier, DBSnapshotARN: DBSnapshotArn, SnapshotCreateTime: SnapshotCreateTime}" \
 --no-paginate --output json
```

I could also get the **top 5 records** from this query by replacing `[*]` with `[:5]`:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier sample-db \
 --query="(reverse(sort_by(DBSnapshots[?SnapshotType=='manual'], &SnapshotCreateTime)))[:5].{DBSnapshotIdentifier: DBSnapshotIdentifier, DBSnapshotARN: DBSnapshotArn, SnapshotCreateTime: SnapshotCreateTime}" \
 --no-paginate --output json
```

However, I would like to get all the records **excluding top 5**. I would appreciate any inputs on JMES Path on how could I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to achieve is called [slicing](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#slicing), and you where actually pretty close with your trial to a solution.

The slicing syntax of JMESPath is borrowed from the Python world and is as follow:

> This syntax introduces Python style array slicing that allows a start
> position, stop position, and step. This syntax also proposes following
> the same semantics as python slices.
>
> `[start:stop:step]`
>
> Each part of the expression is optional. You can omit the start
> position, stop position, or step. No more than three values can be
> provided in a slice expression.
>
> The step value determines how my indices to skip after each element is
> plucked from the array. A step of 1 (the default step) will not skip
> any indices. A step value of 2 will skip every other index while
> plucking values from an array. A step value of -1 will extract values
> in reverse order from the array. A step value of -2 will extract
> values in reverse order from the array while, skipping every other
> index.

<sup>*Source: https://jmespath.org/proposals/array-slices.html#syntax*</sup>

So your query should read `[5:]`, to indicate that you want the slice to start after the fifth element, ending up with:

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier sample-db \
 --query="(reverse(sort_by(DBSnapshots[?SnapshotType=='manual'], &SnapshotCreateTime)))[5:].{DBSnapshotIdentifier: DBSnapshotIdentifier, DBSnapshotARN: DBSnapshotArn, SnapshotCreateTime: SnapshotCreateTime}" \
 --no-paginate --output json
```